# Algorithm for removing duplicates from Json Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, search

I have this JSON Data:

```
[{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade","year":"2006"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade","year":"2005"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade","year":"2004"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade","year":"2003"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade","year":"2002"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade ESV","year":"2006"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade ESV","year":"2005"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade ESV","year":"2004"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade ESV","year":"2003"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade EXT","year":"2006"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade EXT","year":"2005"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade EXT","year":"2004"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade EXT","year":"2003"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade EXT","year":"2002"},{"make":"Chevrolet","model":"Astro","year":"2005"},{"make":"Chevrolet","model":"Astro","year":"2004"},{"make":"Chevrolet","model":"Astro","year":"2003"},{"make":"Chevrolet","model":"Avalanche 1500","year":"2006"},{"make":"Chevrolet","model":"Avalanche 1500","year":"2005"}]
```

How do I sort the data format.

```
Cadillac    Escalade    07-13
Cadillac    Escalade ESV    07-13
Cadillac    Escalade EXT    07-13
Cadillac    XTS 2013
Chevrolet   Avalanche   07-13
Chevrolet   Express 1500    09-14
```

I'm still a very fresh with PHP so I'm having a hard time figuring out how to achieve this and removing duplicates as well as adding the years by concatenation.

Thanks,

Comment: what is `07-13`? it doesn't appear within your json data

Comment: adding the years by concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode('[{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade","year":"2006"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade","year":"2005"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade","year":"2004"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade","year":"2003"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade","year":"2002"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade ESV","year":"2006"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade ESV","year":"2005"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade ESV","year":"2004"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade ESV","year":"2003"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade EXT","year":"2006"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade EXT","year":"2005"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade EXT","year":"2004"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade EXT","year":"2003"},{"make":"Cadillac","model":"Escalade EXT","year":"2002"},{"make":"Chevrolet","model":"Astro","year":"2005"},{"make":"Chevrolet","model":"Astro","year":"2004"},{"make":"Chevrolet","model":"Astro","year":"2003"},{"make":"Chevrolet","model":"Avalanche 1500","year":"2006"},{"make":"Chevrolet","model":"Avalanche 1500","year":"2005"}]');

// Organize by make and model
foreach ($data as $row) {
  $organized[$row->make][$row->model][] = $row->year;
}

// Output.
foreach ($organized as $make => $models) {
  foreach ($models as $model => $years) {
    sort($years);
    // Use first value as range.
    $range = array_shift($years);
    // If there are more years, create a range.
    if (count($years)) {
      // Use last value as end of range.
      $range .= '-' . array_pop($years);
    }
    // Print formatted line with tabs.
    echo $make, "\t", $model, "\t", $range, "\n";
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Cadillac    Escalade    2002-2006
Cadillac    Escalade ESV    2003-2006
Cadillac    Escalade EXT    2002-2006
Chevrolet   Astro   2003-2005
Chevrolet   Avalanche 1500  2005-2006
```

`$organized`, created in the first `foreach`, is a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [Cadillac] => Array
        (
            [Escalade] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2006
                    [1] => 2005
                    [2] => 2004
                    [3] => 2003
                    [4] => 2002
                )

            [Escalade ESV] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2006
                    [1] => 2005
                    [2] => 2004
                    [3] => 2003
                )

            [Escalade EXT] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2006
                    [1] => 2005
                    [2] => 2004
                    [3] => 2003
                    [4] => 2002
                )

        )

    [Chevrolet] => Array
        (
            [Astro] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2005
                    [1] => 2004
                    [2] => 2003
                )

            [Avalanche 1500] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2006
                    [1] => 2005
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: That's elegant I've been trying for 2 days, Can you please refactor with if statements instead of ternary operation ? Maybe also explain what happening withthe two foreach loops and sorting ? Some additional comments just so I can really grab the logic behind this. Well done though it's exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: @hayonj, I added a bit more detail.

Comment: i'm not i understand the ` if (count($years))` I would have used a for loop on it can you explain what it does ?

Comment: As you can see from the dump of the array I added to my answer, $years becomes an array of all the years available in the JSON data. What I am doing with `count($years)` is checking to see if there are more values in order to create the range of years. `array_shift` removes the first item from the array.  If count returns anything, I know I need to create a range of years.

Comment: your first piece of code before refactoring was this : `$sorted = array_map(function ($arr) {
  return array_map(function ($a) {
    sort($a);
    return $a;
  }, $arr);
}, $organized);` Can you explain what's happening with the array_map and anonymous function ? Thanks.

Comment: @hayonj, it was an overly complicated way of walking through each of the elements in order to sort the years. It was replaced with adding `sort($years)` to the nested `foreach` output loop.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to parse it with a loop. A simple version of that looks something like:

```
$cars = json_decode($cars_json);
$carList = array();
foreach($cars as $car){
    if(!isset($carList[$car->make . $car->model])){
        $carList[$car->make . $car->model] = array(
            'firstYear' => $car->year,
            'lastYear' => $car->year,
            'make'=>$car->make,
            'model' => $car->model,
    }
    else{
        if($car->year < $carList[$car->make . $car->model]['firstYear'])
            $carList[$car->make . $car->model]['firstYear'] = $car->year;
        else if($car->year > $carList[$car->make . $car->model]['lastYear'])
            $carList[$car->make . $car->model]['lastYear'] = $car->year;
    }
}
//Parsing complete, now output

foreach($carList as $car){
  echo $car['make'] . " ";
  echo $car['model'] . " ";
  echo substr($car['firstYear'],-2) . "-" . substr($car['lastYear'], -2);
}
```